# Spell check doesn't work well in lightning input rich text

Tags: lightning, richtextarea, lightninginput, inputrichtext

I'm having a lightning out app in which I'm having a custom rich text field. When I try to correct the spelling for the misspelled words, it's stripping out the entire line instead of correcting the spelling.

When I browsed, I came to know that Lightning supports browser based spell check. My customer has spell check "ON" in his browser (Google Chrome).

Can you please tell what could be the reason behind this behavior? And please find the code below in lighting component.

```
<lightning:inputRichText value="{!v.richTextField__C}" placeholder = "Enter your comments here" shareWithEntityId = "{!v.caseRecordId}">
  <lightning:insertImageButton/>
</lightning:inputRichText>
```